# Configure popup to exclude blank fields

Tags: arcgis-online

I have a layer that lists addresses and dates that address was visited (Oct 23-Nov 20). I want to configure the popup to only display dates that were marked as being visited instead of every date possible.

Comment: What does "every date possible" mean in this context.  It sounds like some addresses were visited on every date possible, but I'm guessing that's not what you really mean.  Perhaps a screenshot to illustrate the issue might be useful here.  (Be sure to edit your question with any clarifications or any extra information).

Comment: As Son of a Beach mentions... Depending on how the data is structured this is something that could be pretty simply solved with an attribute expression.